# Ansible simple inventory for dhcp hosts in yaml

Tags: ansible, yaml

Need a little hint on yaml syntax for a very simple inventory file.

I want to include dhcp range of workstations in a nice inventory file.
Regarding the official documentation this could be done but i'm not on the right track Need a little clue.

```
---
all:
  hosts:
    site0:
      hosts:
        192.168.0.[100:200]
    site1:
      hosts:
        192.168.1.[100:200]
    site2:
      hosts:
        192.164.2.[100:200]
    site3:
      hosts:
        192.168.3.[1.50]
```

Can someone help me to achieve this ?
Thanks

Comment: appart from the missing semi-colons at the end of every line with an ip/range in your above file to make it a correct yaml hence a correct yaml ansible inventory, what is the exact problem you are facing ?

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. I added the semicolon. Still i have this error :                         `site0 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: Could not resolve hostname site0: Name or service not known",
    "unreachable": true
}
`

Comment: Sorry typo in my first message, I should have written "colons". Meanwhile, veryfing your file with `yamllint` and/or `ansible-lint` and/or `ansible-inventory` should give you a direct clue.

Comment: End up doing the correct syntax :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

End up the syntax ini *.ini hostfile is :

```
[workstations_site1]
10.17.3.[1:250]
```

Not a good practice at all you shoud be using nmap inventory plugin .

Now i use now ansible-pull, that's more convenient ansible being agentless.